# react-dom - An update to ... inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have the following component that loads data from an external API using the `useEffect` hook on mount:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "./common/Dropdown";

import { getWeapons } from "../services/gear";

import { DropdownOptionType } from "./common/Dropdown";

const EMPTY_OPTION = {
  key: "0",
  label: "",
  value: "null"
};

const Gear = () => {
  const [weaponOptions, setWeaponOptions] = useState([EMPTY_OPTION]);
  const [weapon, setWeapon] = useState("null");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWeaponsOptions = async (): Promise<void> => {
      const weaponsData = await getWeapons();
      const newWeaponOptions: DropdownOptionType[] = [
        EMPTY_OPTION,
        ...weaponsData.map(({ id, name }) => {
          return {
            key: id,
            label: name,
            value: id
          };
        })
      ];
      setWeaponOptions(newWeaponOptions);
    };

    fetchWeaponsOptions();
  }, []);

  // TODO add weapon dropdown on change, selected weapon state
  const handleWeaponChange = ({ value }: DropdownOptionType): void => {
    setWeapon(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Gear:</h2>
      <Dropdown
        defaultValue={weapon}
        label="Weapon"
        name="weapon"
        options={weaponOptions}
        onChange={handleWeaponChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gear;
```

I am mounting this component inside my App Component:

```
import React from "react";

import Stats from "./components/Stats";
import Gear from "./components/Gear";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Untitled combat game character creator</h1>
      <Stats />
      <Gear />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have the following test for my App component:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("renders app title", () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const titleElement = getByText(/Untitled combat game character creator/i);
  expect(titleElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

The test is passing but outputs the following warning:

> PASS  src/App.test.tsx   ● Console
>
> ```
> console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:530
>   Warning: An update to Gear inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
>
>   When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
>
>   act(() => {
>     /* fire events that update state */
>   });
>   /* assert on the output */
>
>   This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at ...
>       in Gear (at App.tsx:11)
>       in div (at App.tsx:8)
>       in App (at App.test.tsx:6)
> ```

I tried wrapping the test code inside the act callback, but I am getting the same warning:

```
test("renders app title", () => {
  act(() => {
    const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    const titleElement = getByText(/Untitled combat game character creator/i);
    expect(titleElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

And:

```
test("renders app title", () => {
  let titleElement;
  act(() => {
    const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    titleElement = getByText(/Untitled combat game character creator/i);
  });
  expect(titleElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

But I am getting the same warning in both cases. What would be the correct way to handle this?

Comment: @AneesMuhammed That solved it, although the correct syntax is `await act(async () => {...}`. If you post it as an answer with a short explanation of why this is correct I will accept it :)

Comment: If you have working code, could you add an answer of your own? @Anees' comment got deleted

Comment: where is the answer?